# How to convert contractions words back in NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I need to convert abbreviations back using NLP.
Like `what's` to `what is`, `it's` to `it is`, etc.
I want to use it to preprocess the raw sentence.

Actually, I also confused about whether I should do this or just simply remove the `'` and convert `what's` to `whats`. Otherwise, anyway, `is` will be removed as a stop word in a later step.

In another hand, should we consider `whats` and `what` as `lemma`?
Or, we should use stemmer to cut the `s` off?

BTW, I don't think abbreviation is the right term here, but I'm not good at English as well. So, please introduce me the formal NLP or linguistics term we used for `what's`, `how's`, etc.

Comment: They're called contractions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking about this word for quite a while, I saw it somewhere before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, NLP libraries such as [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101) and [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) do a good job doing tokenization transforming like `"It's"` into  `["It", "'s"]`. but transforming something like `what's` into `["what", "is"]` is more problematic, because you can have examples such `"Amy's ballet studio" where the "'s" is not "is".

You could map all cases (he's, I'm, what's, etc) and add new rules to the tokenizer, Spacy allows that:

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH, LEMMA, POS, TAG

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"He's buying that")  # phrase to tokenize
print([w.text for w in doc])  # ['He', "'s", "buying", 'that']

# add special case rule
special_case = [{ORTH: u"He'", LEMMA: u"He", POS: u"PRONOUM"}, {ORTH: u"is"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u"He's", special_case)

# check new tokenization
print([w.text for w in nlp(u"He's buying that")])  # ["He'", "is", "buying", "that"]
```

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/widiger-anna/deefac010da426911381c118a97fc23f) does an extensive job on setting those rules.
But I'm not sure if it is worth doing so, maybe it will not have a great impact on the task you have at hand.

Comment: Got it. I noticed what libraries like NLTK did. We tokenized it as `[It, 's]`, then feed it to the neural network, based on large data, the model will kind of "understand" the corresponding original format and predict correct words as outputs.

Comment: Yeah, I've being running some NLP models using that tokenization, and I did not had any problem regarding this.